# octave ode program produces an unexplained error

Tags: octave

Have a file called f.m which has the following:

function xdot = f (x,t)
    xdot = -exp(-t)*x^2;
endfunction

x=lsode("f",2,(t=linspace(0,5,50)'));
plot(t,x)

Running in octave 4.2.2 or 4.2.1 produces the following error:
error: 't' undefined near line 2 column 14
error: called from
    f at line 2 column 6

Comment: This works since in Jupyter notebook, Octave Kernel v0.28.3 running GNU Octave v4.2.1 on a windows 10 desktop

Comment: The solution is to have the calling function in another file